# NVIDIA GTX1650, GPU Has fallen off the bus

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, suspend

I recently got a new laptop and its been working fine in all other respects but when I go to resume from suspend I get `Xid 79, GPU Has fallen off the bus.`
It's a Dell laptop (xps 15), i9-9980HK CPU, GTX 1650, Ubuntu 18.04, NVIDIA 440 drivers.
I Found a number of people who've had similar issues, but most of them related to random crashes.
There are a couple of suggestions I've tried to fix it: enable persistence mode, `nvidia-settings -a` `'[gpu:0]/GPUPowerMizerMode=1'`, `nvidia-smi -pm 1`, adding `acpi_osi='Windows 2009'`, `pcie_aspm=off` and `rcutree.rcu_idle_gp_delay=1` in various combinations to the boot options.

Persistence mode doesn't seem to be persistent to begin with, when I set it, next time I boot it's disabled (not sure if its supposed to save or not).

Ran around with the laptop in windows for a couple of days but, couldn't cause it to have the same problem.

Any suggestions as to what else I could do would be really appreciated.

Comment: 1) Persistence is for LiveUSBs. Are you running Ubuntu from a LiveUSB, or did you install it to a drive in the laptop as dual-boot? Please click [edit] and answer in your question. 2) The correct driver for NVIDIA's GTX1050 is version 430.09, not 440 - see https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/146629/en-us then please either change to that driver or confirm it's been done.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue with the same notebook and driver. Have you solved it?

Comment: I never could actually solve this issue. Moving to 20.04 did however solve the issue... there was one thing i found that pointed at the issue being in the linux kernel itself (though not exactly cause of the nvidia drivers) and is resolved in the the kernel in 20.04, since then i've not had the issue

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same suspending/wake-up problem as you for the same laptop with Ubuntu 19.10. And it was very frustrating to realize that none of the suggestions around (persistence etc) fix it.

My driver was version 435.21, so initially I tried switching to 440.36 like you but the problem insisted.

@K7AAY, I guess you mean GTX-1650? As this is the OP card and the link says that 440 has added support for it.

Anyway, somehow I got it working by downgrading the driver from 435.21 to 430.09 and then back again to 435.21, so something must be broken along the line. Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm using 19.10 too, and same issue, but I can't see 440 in apt, I only see 430 and 435. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For those who fix the issue by forcing performance mode. Here are two ways to fix this on every boot:
One workaround is to simply add the setting on every boot by adding this to your Startup Apps (or boot scripts, or systemd units, etc):

```
sh -c 'nvidia-settings -a "[gpu:0]/GpuPowerMizerMode=1"'
```

--IMPORTANT: make sure the gpu index is correct as explained in the following section.--

But if you have several settings that you'd like to save, then here is how to properly load your custom nvidia settings on every login and not lose them when the nvidia-settings app tries to overwrite them:

1. run this to get your gpu index (either gpu:0, gpu:1, etc etc):

   ```
   nvidia-settings -q all | grep -C 10 -i powermizer
   ```
2. Now that you know your gpu id, open nvidia-settings -> nvidia settings Configuration -> Save Curent Configuration -> save it in your home as `.persistent_nvidia-settings-rc`
3. Open the new file with a text editor and add this line at the bottom:

   ```
   [gpu:0]/GPUPowerMizerMode=1
   ```
4. Save your settings and verify it works by running this command. Check PowerMizer is set to maximum performance mode afterwards:

   ```
   nvidia-settings --config=$HOME/.persistent_nvidia-settings-rc --load-config-only
   ```
5. Open your Desktop Environment "Startup Apps" configuration. Find and modify the nvidia settings entry (it's already present in Ubuntu) to match this command, or add it if it's not present already:

   ```
   sh -c '/usr/bin/nvidia-settings --config=$HOME/.persistent_nvidia-settings-rc --load-config-only'
   ```
6. Profit

Now the configuration gets loaded when you log in. You can call that from any place to load your settings file, either from OpenRC, Systemd, or your startup apps, as I explained above.

This workaround fixed my issues when the gpu was under load and froze the entire system with `GPU has fallen off the bus` message.

IMPORTANT NOTICE: `nvidia-settings` overwrites the `.nvidia-settings-rc` file by default on each start and DOES NOT save the powermizer settings, that's why we have to create and load a custom file, otherwise the changes would be lost every time you use the app.
After these changes you will have to manually update the `.persistent_nvidia-settings-rc` if you want to change something and get it on every boot, but it's a small pain compared to being unable to use the GPU at all.